# How to change text inside a bootstrap modal on link click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are links to various articles on my Webpage that open an article in a Bootstrap modal. Inside the body of Modal there are two links, one to previous article and other to next article. As of now, when a user clicks on any of these links inside of showing the content inside the modal, the link loads in the browser itself. Here is what my modal function looks like :

```
 function openModal() {
  // Store vallues in variables: var url , urlSplit, mainPage, txt, content
  // prevLink, nextLink, imageURL etc.
  // All of them have correct values.

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'getarticle.php',
  data: {
    link: url,
    page: mainPage
  },
  success: function(data) {
  var moreLinks =  '<a class="modal-link" href="'+nextLink+'">Next</a>';
  data = data+moreLinks;
  $('.feed-modal .modal-body').html(data);
  $('.progress').fadeOut();
}
});
}
```

The `openModal` function is triggered by :

```
$('a.modal-link').on('click', openModal);
```

So, a click on `moreLinks` should change the text inside the Modal but it instead loads the link in browser. How can I just load the content in Modal?

Answer (score 0):

as the link is dynamically added to the DOM, you need to use event delegation:-

```
$('.feed-modal').on('click', 'a.modal-link', openModal);
```

and add `event` to `openModal()` so you can `event.preventDefault();` to stop the `a`'s default behaviour in loading in the browser:-

```
function openModal(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `onclick` handler on the link inside modal.

```js
// Event delegation approach as the link are genrated dynamically.
$(document).on("click", ".modal-link", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent redirection on button click
  $('.progress').fadeIn(); // Fadein the progress
  var url = this.href;
  var mainPage = ""; // Set it to something , i dont know what it is.
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'getarticle.php',
    data: {
      link: url,
      page: mainPage
    },
    success: function(data) {
      
      // Rest all code to update the content is same.
      var moreLinks = '<a class="modal-link" href="' + nextLink + '">Next</a>';
      data = data + moreLinks;
      $('.feed-modal .modal-body').html(data);
      $('.progress').fadeOut();
      
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: The link still loads in the browser.